# Magento2 - Managing Module Activation at Store Level

Tags: magento2, multistore, core, stores

Is it possible to manage activation of a Magento module at the store level.

I am aware that there is a setting to `Disable Modules Output` at `Stores -> Configuration -> ADVANCED -> Advanced -> Disable Modules Output`, but this only disables the module output, but the module is still loaded, and any core functionality changes and rewrites are still in play.

I am looking for a way to only load those custom modules which are needed for that particular store only.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Are you able to fix this?

Comment: @AniruddhaADeshpande not at the moment buddy, still trying to figure it out